# tempfile gives wrong absolutepath after renameto

Tags: java, file

I'm changing contents of a file, therefore I read a file line by line, replace what I want and write line by line to a tempfiles. When the whole file is processed, I delete the original file, and rename the tempfile to the original filename.
like this

```
File orginialFile = new File("C:\\java\\workspace\\original.xml");
File tempFile = File.createTempFile("tempfile", ".tmp", new File(C:\\java\\workspace\\"));
while ((str_String = reader.readLine()) != null) {
//read lines and replace and write lines
}
orginialFile .delete();     
tempFile.renameTo(new File("C:\\java\\workspace\\original.xml"));
```

After this is done, I request the absolutepath (tempFile.getAbsolutePath();) of the temp file. But this gives me
c:\java\workspace\tempfile3729727953777802965.tmp (the number changes every run of the program) in stead of c:\java\workspace\original.xml

How come?

I debugged it and just before the moment that I request the absolutepath, I checked in c:\java\workspace (windows explorer) and there is no tempfile. Only original file.

So the process runs correctly, I just wanted to know why it is not showing the renamed absolutepath. (I would use it for logging)

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the documentation of [`java.io.File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html), before the **Interoperability with `java.nio.file` package**:

> Instances of the File class are immutable; that is, once created, the abstract pathname represented by a File object will never change.

So it won't show the renamed absolutepath.

Answer (score 1):

There is a missing `reader.close()` before the delete. *Likely edited out for us.* Also you can do:

```
tempFile.renameTo(originialFile);
```

Comment: the reader.close is in my code.Indeed just left out. Your suggestion is good. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the return value from renameTo()? I suspect it to be false.

Also pay attention to the [api documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29). It states that a lot of things can go wrong - e.g. moving between file systems.

You might be better off with [Files.move](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/move.html)